# How to place markers by tapping at google maps in iOS using swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

How to place markers by tapping at google maps in iOS using swift? Code is as follows:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) 
{   
    let markerr = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
    markerr.position.latitude = coordinate.latitude
    markerr.position.longitude = coordinate.longitude
    print("hello")
    print(markerr.position.latitude)
    let ULlocation = markerr.position.latitude
    let ULlgocation = markerr.position.longitude
    print(ULlocation)
    print(ULlgocation)
    markerr.map = self.googleMapsView
    mapView.delegate = self
 }
```

Comment: no need to use this line `mapView.delegate = self` as well as what the issue u faced

Comment: did tap function is not working

Comment: you mean this method is not called `func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)` correct or else

Comment: called `You just have to initialize delegate at `viewDidLoad`

   `mapView.delegate = self`

Comment: see this for e.g https://theappspace.com/google-maps-sdk-ios-using-swift-4/

Comment: try  `mapView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: I got this error:   Value of type '(GMSMapView, CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> ()' has no member 'delegate'

Answer (score 1):

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    mapView.clear()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
        self.marker.position = position
        self.marker.map = mapView
        self.marker.icon = UIImage(named: "default_marker")
        print("New Marker Lat Long - ",coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have done the following correctly.

1. Set `GMSMapViewDelegate`
2. set `mapView.delegate = self` inside your ViewDidLoad() (Not in `mapVieWdidTapAt` function. Otherwise this function is not going to be called.)
3. Set `mapVieWdidTapAt` function

   ```
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
           mapView.clear()
           let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
           let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
           marker.title = "Hello World"
           marker.map = mapView

       }
   ```